Short story in which a computer declares itself "God"
I recall a short story where a new computer is constructed.  And the Mayor of Earth turns it on and asks the ultimate first question - "Is there God?".  A lightning bolt fuses the switch to ON permanently and the computer says "There is now".
I am sure Isaac Asimov wrote it, but I could be wrong.  I am looking for the collection/book it is in.

Are you confident that this story would only have been published within one collection, rather than several? If so, why? And do you recall anything about any of the other stories in the collection you're looking for?

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82767/rogue-ai-story-mentioned-by-stephen-hawking-on-last-week-tonight

Even without registering, you can search the Internet Archive copy of Angels and Spaceships for the word "God". See the two quotes from p. 37. https://archive.org/details/angelsspaceships0000fred/page/36/mode/2up?q=god

@user14111, that link points to the correct text as I recall it.  That is the correct story.  I don't have that collection though.  Now I just need to find which one of the books I own has that story.  :-)

@RohitGupta The ISFDB page for that story lists the books it's been published in https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41656 under these covers https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?41656

That's "Answer" by Fredric Brown. Anthologised in "Angels and Spaceships" and doubtless lots of other places too. An oldie from the 1950s.

https://www.roma1.infn.it/~anzel/answer.html You can read it here. Certainly one of the most concise science fiction stories I've read.
